# Error message when starting PeerGuardian

Tags: networking, installed-programs

I recently installed PeerGuardian on the latest Ubuntu build and received the following error message:

[image]

No idea why this message is coming up. I tried searching for the error online but did not find anyone else with the same issue.

UPDATE: After un-installing and trying to re-install PeerGuardian, I get the following error message:

```
pgld will soon be started ...
If any blocklists are missing, they will be downloaded. This may take several
minutes. Please be patient and don't abort. If you want to follow the update
process, then do in another terminal a
 tail -f /var/log/pgl/pglcmd.log
The lists are saved to /var/spool/pgl/.
The installation of pglcmd will fail, if starting pgld fails. So if
downloading the blocklists fails temporarily, the installation will fail. In
this case you may turn the automatic starting off by setting in
/etc/pgl/pglcmd.conf:
 INIT="0"
Then complete the installation and turn the automatic start on again:
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force pglcmd
Please be patient ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for pgl.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status pgl.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript pgl, action "start" failed.
* pgl.service - LSB: PeerGuardian Linux - an IP Blocker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pgl; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-10-25 14:03:47 BST; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 28878 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/pgl start (code=exited, status=9)

Oct 25 14:03:47 * systemd[1]: Starting LSB: PeerGuardian Li....
Oct 25 14:03:47 * pgl[28878]:  * Starting PeerGuardian Linu...d
Oct 25 14:03:47 * pgl[28878]:    ...fail!
Oct 25 14:03:47 * systemd[1]: pgl.service: Control process ...9
Oct 25 14:03:47 * systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: PeerGuar....
Oct 25 14:03:47 * systemd[1]: pgl.service: Unit entered fai....
Oct 25 14:03:47 * systemd[1]: pgl.service: Failed with resu....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package pglcmd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pglgui:
 pglgui depends on pglcmd (= 2.3.1-1~xenial); however:
  Package pglcmd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pglgui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 pglcmd
 pglgui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have `gksu` installed?

Comment: I do. I thought that might be the issue too but still get the message after installing `gksu`

Comment: How did you installed PG in the first place? With a PPA, compiled from source, etc...?

Comment: I installed PG using this guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-peerguardian-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-ppa/